# How to properly detect ad blocker & display warning?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

We have some custom ad position to display all over the site to a Next.js project. Those ads can be google ads or can be custom ads from local advertisers. Now we need to detect that if any ad blocker preventing those ads to show properly and displaying a warning if any adblocker is active on the browser.

We have tried some NPM packages but any of them not working as expected.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could check if the element becomes hidden.

This for example would be a typical bait:

```
<div id="ad-banner">
  <img src="https://example.com/ad.jpg" />
</div>
```

Of course you should also be able to use your existing ad position. But it makes sense to add a specific element, which screams "Ad" in order to check.

Then you can check if the element has been hidden:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const ad = document.getElementById('ad-banner');
  const isAdBlockActive = ad && ad.offsetHeight === 0;
  if (isAdBlockActive) {
    console.log('We have an AdBlocker!!');
  }
}, []);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your solution I really appreciate it, this works if you have one ad with specified id. BTW, I have managed to solve the situation with another solution that worked in my case.